# Is there a quick trick to write permutations of $S_n$ as products of transpositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations

If I want to write $(123)$ as product of transpositions, I get $(13)(12)$.
For $(132)$ I get $(12)(13)$. For $(1234)$, I get $(14)(13)(12)$. Seems like I can write $(abcd)$ as $(ad)(ac)(ab)$.

Is this is a  general trick that also works for larger $n$?

Edit: As usernull suggested, would this be a correct prove by induction?

Suppose that $(a_1 ... a_n)=(a_1 a_n)...(a_1 a_2)$. Then 
\begin{align}
(a_1 ... a_n a_{n+1})=&(a_1 a_{n+1})(a_1 ... a_n) \\
   \overset{\text{IH}}{=}& (a_1 a_{n+1})(a_1 a_n)...(a_1 a_2)
\end{align}

Comment: Try to prove your claim by induction.

Comment: @nullUser I tried, see edit, is this correct ?

Comment: you got it! See how easy that was ;)

Comment: @nullUser , I dont really understand the inductive proof. Would you mind elaborating? (i.e. why is the first step considered valid?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$(1)$ Yes, as mixedmath points out, one "tried and true" method for writing a product of disjoint cycle as a product of transpositions is the strategy you employ:

For a one-cycle:
$$(a_1\,a_2\,a_3\,\cdots\,a_{n-1}\,a_n) = (a_1\,a_n)(a_1\,a_{n-1})\cdots\,(a_1\,a_3)(a_1\,a_2)$$

For more cycles, say e.g., a three-cycle, you just concatenate each cycle's product of transpositions: 
$$(abcd)(efgh)(ijkl) = \underbrace{(ad)(ac)(ab)}_{\large (abcd)}\,\underbrace{(eh)(eg)(ef)}_{\large (efgh)}\,\underbrace{(il)(ik)(ij)}_{\large(ijkl)}$$

---

*But another fool-proof way to write cycles as products of transpositions is as follows*:

> $$(a_1\,a_2\,a_3\,\cdots\,a_{n-1}\,a_n) = (a_1\,a_2)(a_2\,a_3)\,(a_3\,a_4)\cdots(a_{n-2}\,a_{n-1})(a_{n-1}\,a_n)$$

And again, for more cycles, say e.g., a three-cycle, you just concatenate each cycle's product of transpositions:
$$(abcd)(efgh)(ijkl) = \underbrace{(ab)(bc)(cd)}_{\large (abcd)}\,\underbrace{(ef)(fg)(gh)}_{\large (efgh)}\,\underbrace{(ij)(jk)(kl)}_{\large(ijkl)}$$

---

- What this shows is that there is *no unique* way to write a permutation as a product of transpositions. *What is true* is that no matter which method you use, if it's a correct method, will yield the original cycle(s), when those transpositions are "multiplied out".
- AND for every permutation, whatever the way chosen to express it as of the product of transpositions, the number of transpositions in the product will ALWAYS be **even**, or ALWAYS be **odd**, for any given permutation.

Comment: aah thanks! I like your other fool proof way to write cycles as products of permutations. Is it true that you could write this also the other way around? So: $(a_{n-1} a_n)...(a_1 a_2)$ the same as $(a_1 a_2)...(a_{n-1} a_n)$

Comment: No, it's not.: see what you get, for example, writing $(123) = (12)(34)$: when you multiply the transpositions, you get back $(123)$. But trying to write it as $(23)(12)$ gives you $(132)$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it always works.

$(abcdefg) = (ag)(af)(ae)(ad)(ac)(ab)$, and so on, will always work. One way to 'see it' is to justify that each letter goes to the next letter. Say we want to see what happens to $d$. Then in our product of transpositions, $d$ will be sent to $a$, and in the subsequent transposition $a$ is sent to $e$. Each letter besides $a$ appears exactly once, so we see that $d \to e$. This happens for the $n$th symbol in the exact same way.

Answer (score 1):

For any disjoint cycle $(a_1 a_2 ... a_n)$, you can write it as $(a_1 a_2)(a_1 a_3) \dots (a_1 a_n)$.

For a general permutation, represent it in disjoint cycle notation and then apply the above trick.

Edit:  It appears you are evaluating your permutations with arguments on the right, in which case $(a_1 a_2 \dots a_n) = (a_1 a_n) \dots (a_1 a_3) (a_1 a_2)$ as you say.

Comment: The decomposition in the first sentence is wrong