# $(1 7 3 4)(1 2 3)$ as a product of disjoint cycles and transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am trying to write $(1 7 3 4)(1 2 3)$ as a product of disjoint cycles and as a product of transpositions

**My Attempt**: $(1 7 3 4)(1 2 3)= (1 7 3 4)$ as a product of disjoint cycles as $2$ $5$ and $6$ are all fixed values.

$(1 7 3 4)(1 2 3)= (14)(13)(17)$ as a product of transpositions.

I'm not really sure however if $2$ is fixed here. My understanding is that $1$ is sent to $4$, $4$ is sent to $3$,  $3$ is sent to $7$ and $7$ is sent to $1$.

I feel that I am misreading this and perhaps $7$ is sent to $2$ and $2$ is sent to $1$

I am aware that this site shouldn't be used to check my work however I really need to improve my understanding of these concepts.

Any help here would be great.

Comment: You should get $(1734)(123)=(124)(37)$.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319979/how-to-write-permutations-as-product-of-disjoint-cycles-and-transpositions) on how to do it.  Other duplicates are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586797/ways-of-expressing-permutations-as-products-of-transpositions) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331985/is-there-a-quick-trick-to-write-permutations-of-s-n-as-products-of-transpositi).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys, I see my error now. To verify: $3$ and $7$ are interchanged, $1$ is sent to $4$, $4$ is mapped to $2$ and $2$ is mapped to $1$. With the transposition changing to $(1 4)(1 2)(3 7)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your first step should be to get

$$(1734)(123)=(124)(37),\tag{1}$$

from which you have correctly identified that the RHS of $(1)$ is $(14)(12)(37)$.